# How to access Django method in a view

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django with a method that I can't seem to access in the view.  Here is the model:

```
class Realtor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(RealtorTeam, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    is_showing_realtor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_listing_realtor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def type(self):
        if self.is_showing_realtor and self.is_listing_realtor:
            return 'Showing and Listing'
        elif self.is_showing_realtor:
            return 'Showing'
        elif self.is_listing_realtor:
            return 'Listing'
        else:
            return ''
```

Now, in the view, I try to query the model, including the method, like this:

```
q = Realtor.objects.all()
q = q.filter(user__first_name__icontains=first)
q = q.filter(user__last_name__icontains=last)
q = q.filter(team__name__icontains=team)
q = q.filter(user__email__icontains=email)
q = q.filter(type__icontains=type)
```

The error I get is `Cannot resolve keyword 'type' into field. Choices are...`.  I looked up a number of stackoverflow questions, and read through more of the Django docs, and I saw to add a field like this in the model:

```
type_display = (type,)
```

But that didn't work.  Do I have to query the is_showing_realtor and is_listing_realtor?  Is there no way to query the method?

### More info

We are using Django_tables2 to display tables of models.  We are able to access the `type` method with that, like this:

```
class RealtorTable(tables.Table):
    id = tables.Column()
    first_name = tables.Column(accessor='user.first_name', order_by='user.first_name')
    last_name = tables.Column(accessor='user.last_name', order_by='user.last_name')
    team = tables.Column()
    email = tables.Column(accessor='user.email', order_by='user.email')
    type = tables.Column(order_by='is_showing_realtor')
```

But still, can't pass it to the view.

Answer (score 2):

`type` is the name of a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) python, and so also in django. I'd recommend renaming your function to something like `listing_type` to avoid any clashes.

In particular, this line

```
type_display = (type,)
```

probably isn't doing what you think it is.

[reptilicus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1443118/reptilicus) is correct, I'd not spotted the filter on a non-field attribute, that doesn't make sense. You could turn `listing_type` into a `CharField` with `choices=` set, and then some custom `save()` logic to set it when the model is changed - or you could use `property`

```
@def listing_type():
    doc = "The listing_type property."
    def fget(self):
        if self.is_showing_realtor and self.is_listing_realtor:
            return 'Showing and Listing'
        elif self.is_showing_realtor:
            return 'Showing'
        elif self.is_listing_realtor:
            return 'Listing'
        else:
            return ''
    def fset(self, value):
        self._listing_type = value
    def fdel(self):
        del self._listing_type
    return locals()
listing_type = property(**listing_type())
```

PS I still don't like `type` :-)

Comment: There haven't been any clashes.  Just can't access it in the view.  We are using django_tables2, and we can access `type` in that. Perhaps I'll add that to my question for elaboration.

Comment: I'd double check - the `type_display = (type,)` line is suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm  no Django expert, but I'm pretty sure that you can't query on model attributes that aren't columns in the database, which is what you are trying to do. Perhaps try to decorate the method with `@property` to make it like an attribute.

You could just do a list comprehension if like

```
results = [m for m in query_set if m.type = "Showing and listing"]
```

Comment: I'm no Django expert either, so this seems to me to be the simplest solution.